# I need to submit user input as part of a get request to the unsplash server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

is it possible to get the keyword before the get request to the unsplash server so as to trigger a live search? I would like to use user input for the keyword. This is my code on the front end

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()

    this.state = {
      images: [],
      keyword: '',
      count: 15,
      start: 1
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { count, start, keyword } = this.state;
    axios
      .get(`api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}&keyword=${keyword}`)
      .then(res => this.setState({images: res.data.results}))
  }

  searchChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your need, but if you want to do a realtime search, you can use the lifecycle methods **componentDidUpdate** and **shouldComponentUpdate**, as below :

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            images: [],
            keyword: '',
            count: 15,
            start: 1
        }
        this.searchChange = this.searchChange.bind(this)
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        return nextState.keyword != this.state.keyword
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        const { count, start, keyword } = this.state;
        axios
          .get(`api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}&keyword=${keyword}`)
          .then(res => this.setState({images: res.data.results}))
    }
    searchChange(e) {
        this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value })
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.searchChange} />
        </div>
    }
}
```